# How to get all base model from a stackedsamble in h2o

Tags: python, h2o

I used H2O's automl on my dataset, and the top model is a stackedensemble model. I like to get all basemodels with it's parameters of this stacked model. How do I get this models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `aml.leader` to get the top model or you can use [get_best_model](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/automl.html#examine-models) to pick the model by some criterium. If you want to pick some specific model from the leaderboard you can use `h2o.get_model("model_id")` (the model_id is from the leaderboard).

To get parameters from all the base models you can use the following:

```py
{base_model: h2o.get_model(base_model).actual_params
 for base_model in h2o.get_model("model_id").base_models}
```

You might also want to get parameters from the stacked ensemble and the metalearner:

```py
metalearner_params = h2o.get_model("SE_model_id").metalearner().actual_params
se_params = h2o.get_model("SE_model_id").actual_params
```